# How to use an arrow function as a property in JS/TS functional programming

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

Assuming I would make a constructor of a functional class with `TypeA`: some argument, and `TypeB`: the type of the class itself, I can use

```
functionName(argument: TypeA): TypeB {
    this.property = argument;
    return this;
  }
```

but cannot use

```
property: (argument: TypeA): TypeB => ({
    property: argument,
    ...
  })
```

I understand this is due to the difference in `this` when I use an arrow function and normal function.

Then, how can I use an arrow function which will work like the first case with normal function?

Example:

```
import personConst from './personConst';
// const personConst: { [key: string]: UnitBase } = {
//   brah: {
//     name: "Thomas",
//     age: 25,
//     gender: "male"
//   },
//   hoge: {
//     name: "Sarah",
//     age: 29,
//     gender: "female"
//   },
//   ...
// }

import { PersonBase } from './PersonBase';
// export interface UnitBase {
//   name: string;
//   age: number;
//   gender: string;
// }


interface Person extends PersonBase {
  income: number;
  zip: number;
  setIncome(newIncome: number): this;
  setZip(newZip: number): this;
}

const person = (key: string): Person => ({
  income: 50000,
  zip: 50000,
  setIncome: (newHp: number): Person => ({
    income: newIncome,
    ... // Error: Expression expected.
  }),
  setZip(newZip: number): Person {
    this.zip = newZip;
    return this; // OK
  },
  ...personConst[key]
});

export default person;
```

Comment: I don't see any code that *calls* the constructor, but anyway, it is part of the language specification that arrow functions cannot be constructors, i.e. you cannot call them with `new`.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  An arrow function doesn't have its own `this` context, so you probably shouldn't use one to implement an object method.  You can use anonymous functions instead, if you want... but why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question, but if you want to use the `this` context, you shouldn't use an arrow function `x => y` directly. Instead you can just use the more verbose anonymous function `(function(x){ return y })` syntax:

```
const person = (key: string): Person => ({
  income: 50000,
  zip: 50000,
  setIncome: function(newIncome: number): Person { // anonymous function
    return {
      ...this, 
      income: newIncome
    };
  },
  setZip(newZip: number): Person {
    this.zip = newZip;
    return this; // OK
  },
  ...personConst[key]
});
```

I *think* this behaves as you want:

```
const thomas = person("brah");

console.log(thomas.zip); // 50000
thomas.setZip(10301);
console.log(thomas.zip); // 10301

console.log(thomas.income); // 50000
thomas.setIncome(100000);
console.log(thomas.income); // 50000
const newThomas = thomas.setIncome(100000);
console.log(newThomas.income); // 100000
```

but I can't tell from your question.  Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#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-lEPt4E1ulEARl5AGZebOW22VB2uz3JwPhcPE8h50vZ63DOuIJ3u724v2TTaIHvRwLeRPr1OJSqqD950-V6eN5ft1vD97zjfcx2fNtiTtWIq12bxAPfb4vyfXlf3UM8Lx7aDXwHO8HwPFCiCAA)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Indeed even I was not sure the point. Eventually, it seems that regardless either for constructor or other purposes, I cannot use an arrow function if the return value need to depend on `this` of current context, right? I thought there might be another syntax that enabled me to use an arrow function, which returns the class instance itself, as a properties of the class but seems not.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use fat arrow anywhere. Its mostly used:
- Using fat arrow (=>) we drop the need to use the 'function' keyword. Its anonymous function
- To avoid bindings in constructor you can use ( =>)
- For functions like doSomething(){ }, you can not use fat arrow here. But eg: function (){ } , you can use lambda here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but isn't it contradict to what @jcalz mentioned...?

Comment: Yeah @seed.of.apricot what I said is not totally wrong. I read about it so out come is:
Function expressions are best for object methods. Arrow functions are best for callbacks or methods like map, reduce, or forEach.
I read from : https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e
I have used what I said above but mostly in callback not for object function.